# Can jmethodID initialized on one thread be used in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

Can we use `jmethodID` intialized on one thread in another thread ? I asked this because my jvm is crashing when i run the jni program,in which i have initialized `jmethodID` on one thread and using it in another thread. I was thinking if this could be a reason.

I have kept `jmethodID` as a global varibale by declaring at the top. Then in one of the call I initialize it and in the subsequent calls i attempt to reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715):

> A field or method ID does not prevent the VM from unloading the class
>   from which the ID has been derived. After the class is unloaded, the
>   method or field ID becomes invalid. The native code, therefore, must
>   make sure to:
>
> ```
> keep a live reference to the underlying class, or
>
> recompute the method or field ID
> ```
>
> if it intends to use a method or field ID for an extended period of
>   time.

Comment: @SuhailGupta That would be 'intend[ing] to use a method or field ID for an extended period of time'. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: i meant to say _between the calls_ .

Comment: @SuhailGupta It should be perfectly clear from what I have quoted that the answer is 'no', and what actions are necessary if you want it to be 'yes'.

Comment: This answer does not relate to threading, it relates to lifetime of jclass objects.

Comment: @user207421 how are you seeing the relation?  My understanding is that jclass objects are deallocated when the jni function returns, without regard to behavior of other threads.  The quesiton is about concurrent use of jmethodIDs.  What you say is a reference needs to be kept around for them to be valid, but it's left open whether or not they can be used from other threads.  They could be used with their reference deallocated from the same thread, as much as from a different one.